# A $3\times3$ Matrix such $A^{5}=I$, Prove $A=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some problems in this problem of linear algebra.

Let $A\in\mathbf{M}_{3\times3}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $A^{5}=I_{3\times3}$, where $I_{3\times3}$ is the identity matrix. Prove $A=I$.

**My proof attempt**

Let $A$, we asume $A^{5}=I_{3\times3}$, then we can use a little trick for this, let $O_{3\times3}$ the zero of matrices $3\times3$, then:
$$A^{5}=I_{3\times3}\Rightarrow A^{5}-I_{3\times3}=O_{3\times3}$$
So we are going to use the *cube difference (For fifth power)*:
$$\Rightarrow (A-I_{3\times3})(A^{4}+A^{3}+A^{2}+A+I_{3\times3})=0$$

**First Case:** $(A-I_{3\times3})=O_{3\times3}\Rightarrow A=I_{3\times3}\blacksquare$

**Second Case:** $A^{4}+A^{3}+A^{2}+A+I_{3\times3}=0\dots$

I don't know how to proceed with this, I was thinking in Cayley-Hamilton theorem but the polinomio is grade 4 and the matrices are *"grade 3"*. What can I do? Thanks 4 ur time c:

Comment: Hint: The Cayley Hamilton shows that there is some cubic relation in terms of $$A$$. This means there is some cubic polynomial that divides $$t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1$$. Can you show that this quartic polynomial is irreducible over the rationals?

Comment: Two cases do not work. There are examples where $A$ and $B$ are both not zero but $AB = O$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you have a matrix equation $AB = O$, you cannot conclude $A = O$ or $B = O$. What this means in your question is that there are more than the two cases that you consider.

---

We can use some knowledge of minimal polynomials here. Let $m(t)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. Since $A$ is $3 \times 3$, the minimal polynomial is of degree at most $3$.
Now, since $A^5 = I$, it follows that $m(t)$ divides $t^5 - 1$. As you have noted, the polynomial factors as
$$t^5 - 1 = (t - 1)(t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1).$$
Now, the degree $4$ polynomial is irreducible (check). Thus, the only factor of $t^5 - 1$ which is of degree $\leq 3$ is $t - 1$. But this means that $A$ satisfies $A - I = 0$; equivalently, $A = I$, as desired.